# Replace Ruby IO libraries with async versions + fibers

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, nonblocking, fibers

Is it possible to replace all ruby IO clases with different implementation, that uses reactor and fibers behind the scene? I mean that in fact all libraries, that uses native ruby IO will work as expected, because of all calls to IO will be wrapped with fibers, and they will wait for requested operation. But while waiting when data is available in connection/file ruby will serve other io operations.

Comment: Is it posible? Yes, just monkey-patch `IO`. Is it a *lot* of work? Yes, but if you really want it, do it. If you don't know how to monkey patch IO, make that your question.

Comment: question was about possibility. thx for answer.

Comment: Sure. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it posible? Yes, just monkey-patch IO. Is it a lot of work? Yes, but if you really want it, do it. If you don't know how to monkey patch IO, make that your question.

For example, to override `read`:

```
class IO
  def read(count = -1)
    #Some fiber code here...
  end
end
```

Comment: i think i must write c extention, using for example libev + libeio, it's not possible to do async io in native ruby.

Comment: @h3x3d: It is. Hold on for a moment, let me look in my RUby book.

Comment: @h3x3d: Look at the docs for IO#readpartial, IO#read_nonblock, and IO#write_nonblock.